# php7 show full sqlserver table (header and rows)

Tags: sql-server, php-7

I'm trying to write my first php script.
I've to show in a page the full content of some sql server tables:
therefore record names on the first row and then the content of each row, and googleing for a while I wrote this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $sql="Select * from Shipments";
    $serverName = "TEST"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pwd");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         //print "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         //print "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $result = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql );

    echo "<table><tr>";
    foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $result ) as $field ) {
      echo "<th>";
      echo $field['Name'];
          echo "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

    //here goes rows

    echo "</table>";
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result);
?>
```

but this shows only headers (record names), then I have to add all the rows with values and I was thinking to add this:

```
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $cell)
        {
            echo "<td>";
            echo $cell;
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

but is not working :-(

can suggest solution

Thanks

Comment: what's the error there? what's the results you get?

Comment: actually have not been able to configure debug plugin, therefore do not know what error is, but the result I got is nothing.

I solved using this: 
`while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      //echo count($row);
 
      for ($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
      {
          echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
   }
      echo "</tr>\n";
  }`

but it means I've not understood how hare handled arrays in php, or, $row is different type of array.